# Are there any legal risks to transferring money to another country for an F-1 student?

Tags: united-states, international, finance

Let's assume that your dating an F-1 visa student, who is supposed to be financed by her parents in her home country to go to school in the US. She is actually getting money through other means (working under the table, money from other family in the US, etc). One day she asks you to transfer $4,000 to her parents in her home country because she doesn't want the government finding out that she's making money and it's not her parents that are financing her. What risks does this carry for you?

Comment: You go to jail for fraud and money laundering?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch please don’t answer in comments